# Examples of Hilbert manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, hilbert-spaces, vector-bundles, loop-spaces

I came across the definition of Hilbert manifold on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold) and was hoping to collect some (infinite-dimensional) examples.

I'd be particularly interested in a good reference on the example given in the article about Sobolev maps from $S^1$ to a manifold.

Comment: The book of Klingenberg mentioned in the references of that Wiki page is working extensively with $H^1(S^1 , M)$ to study closed geodesics. While I found it difficult to digest in some places I also found it worth the pain...